# use a function inside shiny server with options being reactive values

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if my question is a bit silly but I can't find a way of making to work a custom function that use reactiveValues as options.

I created several functions to do some "heavy processing" that I have put in `global.R`. These functions are something like this

```
estimateDEG <- function(variables = NULL, design = NULL, ...){
               # do some processing for example
               design <- model.matrix(variables$group[,1]
               d <- estimateDisp(d, design))
               suppressMessages(fit <- glmQLFit(d, design))
               suppressMessages(out <- glmQLFTest(fit, coef = 2))
               p <- out$table$PValue
                
               p[is.na(p)] <- 1
               variables$stat$p.value <<- p
               variables$stat$rank <<- rank(p)
               variables$stat$q.value <<- p.adjust(p, method = "BH")
               variables$stat$logFC <<- out$table$logFC
               ... # more coding
}
```

Then I want to use this function in **server.R**

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      variables <- reactiveValues(
                      group = NULL,
                      stat = list()
                   )

 # for example, I have a button that when it is clicked store some 
 # information in `variables$group` that I want to use in the function `estimateDEG`.

  observeEvent(input$buttonList, {
          group <- fread(input$groupSelectViaText, header = FALSE) # a TextAreaInput from ui.R
          variables$group <- lapply(unique(group$V2), function(x) {
              group[group$V2 == x, ]$V1
          })
         names(variables$group) <- unique(group$V2)                      
})

# and now I would like to use the estimateDEG function in another observeEvent

  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
           
        deg <- reactive(estimateDE(variables = variables,
                    test.method = input$testMethod, # another input from ui.R
                    FDR = input$fdr # another input f
                   )) 
                 })
```

However, when I run this code the `reactiveValues` are not updated, i.e, after running `estimateDEG` the `variables$stat` value is `NULL`. Is there any way of using a function inside server.r that use reactiveValues as options and update another values inside these reactiveValues? I would expect `variables$stat` to be populated with `p.value`, `rank`, `q.value` and so on

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're assigning to global in a shiny app, especially with `<<-` you've likely gone astray.

Reactive values are functions, and any argument passed is the new value of the function. To change the value of a reactive, you cannot use `assign` aka `<-`. This will just reassign the object from a reactive object to a static object in memory. You instead use the new value as the argument for the reactive function object. See below:

If you have the reactive value x, then want to assign its value to 3, you would use:

```
x <- reactiveVal(0)
# then
x(3)
print(x())

## 3
```

In your case, you need to pass the reactive object as a function to be called inside your custom made function. If `x` is a reactive value equal to 0, and I have a function that updates it:

```
f <- function(rval, newval) {
  rval(newval)
}

f(x, 3)
x()

##3
```

To see that in action, the below is a quick demo app.

```
library(shiny)

# function that takes a reactive element as a function
# and returns that element's value plus some
# you can define this in global, under the /R directory
# or even in server. 
add_some <- function(r_val, some) {
  x <- r_val()
  x <- x + some
  r_val(x)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("button", "Button"),
      numericInput("some", "Some", 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("console")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  init <- reactiveVal(0)

  observeEvent(input$button, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    add_some(init, input$some)
  })
  
  output$console <- renderPrint({
    init()
  })
}

shiny::runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Hope that helps.